# C# : Can I iterate Dictionary to get each content?

Tags: c#, dictionary, iteration

I want to iterate to get into every content in following Dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<Subject, ClassPeriodControl> subjectRects;
```

I want to access every ClassPeriodControl object in the dictionary.

How can I iterate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a foreach loop...pair.Value is the object you want.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Subject, ClassPeriodControl> pair in subjectRects)
{
     Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: This results in unnecessary struct copying.  Use `Values`.

Comment: Agree.  You only need to iterate on the pair if you need the Subject and the ClassPeriodControl.  If all you want is the latter, then use Values.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [`Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) property of the Dictionary

```
subjectRects.Values
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary contains collections of keyvaluepair.

So you have to do like

for each KeyValuePair item in subjectRects
{
    item.Subject ="";
item.ClassPeriodControl="";
}

Comment: This results in unnecessary struct copying.  Use `Values`.